# HTML 5 validation Form is missing an action?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
<form class="form" id="main-form" 
    data-entity="Page"
    data-action=@(action)
    data-href="/Admin/Contents/Json@(action)" >
```

It works find and I don't need an action as I handle my submit with javascript and json. However MVC always gives me a warning ( green underline ) saying. HTML5 validation, form is missing an action. Is the form element in HTML5 invalid with no action? It seems strange that I am required to provide one.

Comment: It is no longer required, but the MVC validator isn't updated since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the current W3C HTML5 draft, [the `action` attribute may be omitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#form-submission-0) and defaults to the empty string. I don’t think there has been a change here for a long time.